# What is "Unexpected 'C'" about?

Tags: postman

[image]For a get method, I get a response as Unexpected 'C' on Postman with a request header set Accept = application/json. The produces type is application/json in the rest controller. I would get a 406 error if I don't have the header setting. I have a right response data in a browser.

What is the "Unexpected 'C'" about? And how can I get rid of it?

Update:

I run into a similar problem again today. I attach a screenshot to this question. The error will go away once I remove the Accept in the request header.

Comment: Hi @vic, can you provide a sample of the request, and a screenshot what what you're seeing?

Comment: @EdMeacham For your request, I attach a screenshot to the question. Thanks.

Comment: It looks like you're getting something different that your original issue--Unexpected 'C' is now Unexpected 'H'... regardless, if it's working in the browser, I would try to duplicate the browser's request, and go from there. (Open the developer tools in Chrome or Firebug in Firefox and look at the request in the Network tab)

Answer (score 4):

The expected response is JSON format and you probably write in response a regular string which start with 'C' or 'H'.
Try whether to Create JSON and send it back in response or erase Accept and ContentType application/json and send regular String in response.